# awk formatting white space

Tags: command-line, networking, ip, awk

This is `ip r` output when re-formatting with `awk`. Everything ok except the location of `:` is quite messy due to different interface name.

```
wolf@linux:~$ ip r | awk '{print $3 " : " $1}'
virbr0 : 10.10.0.0/16
wlo1 : 10.10.10.0/24
vboxnet0 : 10.10.11.0/24
virbr0 : 10.10.12.0/24
wolf@linux:~$
```

I thought by using `\t` the problem will go away.

It does for shorter NIC name, but there is still problem with longer name such as `vboxnet0`

```
wolf@linux:~$ ip r | awk '{print $3 "\t : " $1}'
virbr0   : 10.10.0.0/16
wlo1     : 10.10.10.0/24
vboxnet0     : 10.10.11.0/24
virbr0   : 10.10.12.0/24
wolf@linux:~$
```

What is the best way to reformat this?

Expected Output

```
wolf@linux:~$ ip r | awk '{print $3 "\t : " $1}'
virbr0   : 10.10.0.0/16
wlo1     : 10.10.10.0/24
vboxnet0 : 10.10.11.0/24
virbr0   : 10.10.12.0/24
wolf@linux:~$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's more of a job for [`column`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/column.1):

```
ip r | awk '{print $3, ":", $1}' | column -t
```

Applying `column -t` to your input:

```
% cat > foo <EOF
virbr0   : 10.10.0.0/16
wlo1     : 10.10.10.0/24
vboxnet0     : 10.10.11.0/24
virbr0   : 10.10.12.0/24
EOF

% column -t < foo
virbr0    :  10.10.0.0/16
wlo1      :  10.10.10.0/24
vboxnet0  :  10.10.11.0/24
virbr0    :  10.10.12.0/24
```

Comment: Nice. Didn't know `column` command till now. Appreciate for the new knowledge sir.